# Mongodb отличие match и find

Tags: mongodb

в чем отличие find от pipeline "($match", почему большинство использую pipeline-ы?

Зачем тогда нужен find?

Как сделать запрос в виде pipeline?

```
monoappCol.find({'Name': "John" , 'time': {"$in": list(df)}}, 
{"_id":0, "topic":1, 
})
```